# syntax error using arrow function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My handleClick arrow function got unexpected error I have no clue why, couldn't spot any error.

```
class HelloWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.names_holder = [];
      this.state = {
        name: []
      };
    }

    handleClick = () => { //error here
      let random = this.names_holder.concat(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + 3);
      this.setState({
        name: random
      });
    }

    render() {
      return <div className = "widget" >
        < button onClick = {
          this.handleClick
        } > Random concat < /button> {
          JSON.stringify(this.state.name)
        } < /div>;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zLkbfdnm/

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @user2027202827 check my fiddle?

Comment: I tried but I don't see any output there.

Comment: @user2027202827 console.log pls, open ur inspect element.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're build setup is locally but the fiddle doesn't support arrow functions. Could that be the problem you're having?